# How to identify which button was pressed in Raphael?

Tags: javascript, raphael

I have a Raphael code that generates different buttons dynamically. Then I am registering a function to these buttons and I need to identify which specific button was pressed.

In Flash/AS3 you can get the name of button calling the function by writing something like this:

```
function myFunction (e:MouseEvent){
      trace (e.currentTarget.name);
}
```

is there a similar way to achieve this in Raphael?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, since you are using Raphael, I am assuming that you are creating custom buttons with Raphael objects (i.e. rect).
**OK you can do the following:**

1. Create 2 global variables, one to keep a **`count`** of dynamically created button, another to keep the **`id`** of your button in the click event.
2. Every time your Raphael object gets created as a button, assign id to it via data() function.

Example:

```
// global vars
var count = 0;
var id    = 0;


// your code
var paper  = Raphael(0, 0, 1000, 1000);
var button = paper.rect(100, 100, 60, 20, 10).attr({fill: 'red'});
var text   = paper.text(130, 110, "Submit").attr({fill: '#fff'});

count++;

button.data("id", count);

// some more code

button.click(function() 
{
    id = this.data("id");
});
```

Good Luck

Comment: Thanks, this seems to work fine. I also found another usage of the global vars that works, and assigned them to the button as ' button.node.setAttribute("id", count)' and this seems to work fine. I found this then becomes the ID of the DOM element which is quite useful.

Comment: You should accept the answer, so that people will answer to your answers LATER.